# What is the meaning of the preposition 'in' in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-in-context

He was killed in car accident.
I think here 'in' express 'influenced by' am i right?

Comment: The sentence is not close to being grammatical. I have no idea what meaning was actually intended. Do you have a citation for this sentence from an English language source?

Comment: He was killed in *a* car accident? In *the* car accident? In *our* car accident? Maybe it's an actor who got type-cast as "accident victim number three." He got killed in "Car Accident" (the movie)? Anyway, it *seems* to be saying he was *in* a car involved in an accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He was killed in car accident. [image: Red X, indicating invalid form]

This sentence needs a determiner before the word "car", as in any of these examples:

> - He was killed in **a** car accident. [image: Green Check-mark, incarnadining a valid form]
> - He was killed in **the** car accident. [image: Green Check-mark, incarnadining a valid form]
> - He was killed in **this** car accident. [image: Green Check-mark, incarnadining a valid form]
> - He was killed in **another** car accident. [image: Green Check-mark, incarnadining a valid form]
> - He was killed in **last month's** car accident. [image: Green Check-mark, incarnadining a valid form]

Im and of the valid forms above "*in*" means "during the course of". The word "*in*" does not mean "influenced by" in any of these sentences, and I cannot at the moment think of a context in which "in" **would** mean "influenced by".

Comment: They are in trouble because of lateness.Here in mean(influenced by or affected by)=They are affected/influenced by trouble because of lateness, am i correct?

Comment: @Ase I'm afraid not. That is a quite different context, and the meaning of "in" is significantly different there. But it does not mean "influenced by or affected by" in that context either. "In trouble" is a fixed phrase, but it could be described as meaning "in a state of trouble".

Comment: is my interpretation incorrect?Do u don't think i can use 'in' in this sense as i said, plz explain

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is incorrect. No, you cannot validly use "in" in that way. That is just not one of the things the word means.

Comment: I mean "Can i use "in" in this sense in any context"?

Comment: I do not know of **any** context where the use of "in"
 to mean "affected by" would be proper.  I don't think that there is any such context, but English is a complex language, and there might be one I am forgetting or have not learned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138990/discussion-between-ase-and-david-siegel).

Comment: Nothing to chat about. I have said "that isn't valid English" about as strongly as I can.